# Vertical text alignment for bounty (amount), remaining time, and question title?

Tags: bug, design

In [the Bounty tab for a user's Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151918/petahchristian?tab=bounties), is the bounty's remaining time misaligned?

It seems to be *nearly* aligned to the top of the blue rect, as opposed to being baseline aligned with the question title (or amount).

[image]

Is this an intentional misalignment, to more clearly differentiate between the two different texts?  I'm not a designer.  It just appears bit odd as a "superscript" of the image.

*Incidentally, the +100 within the blue rounded rect doesn't appear to be vertically centered in the rect, so the right part of the row apparently has 3 different text baselines.*

This is with Safari 9.0.3 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

Naturally, if this is not `status-bydesign`, please don't delay more important rollouts like Documentation, for such a trivial issue! :)  Thanks for all you do!